# redirect landing without changing url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

I'm working with Apache and Joomla. I would like to have some URIs that land to the same landing page, but avoiding the URL changes.

So, for example:

examplecom/luggage/delay/iberia
examplecom/luggage/delay/aireuropa
examplecom/luggage/delay/ryanair

Need to point to examplecom/luggage/delay but the address bar must show the different airline companies.

I've been messing arround with mod_rewrite with the following codes:

1:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-iberia [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-vueling [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-ryanair [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-aireuropa [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [P]
```

2:

```
RewriteRule ^equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-iberia equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-vueling equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-ryanair equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-aireuropa equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [NC,L]
```

The idea is to have different urls for AdWords but then I'll avoid the indexing of that company landpages to avoid replicated content.

I've been searching for several examples and trying to understand how the module works, but until now I haven't acomplished with that...

Is it possible to do that with mod_rewrite?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two localpaths using flag [P], but if you take your first try and change the rewrite rule to use the full url, it should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-iberia [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-vueling [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-ryanair [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje-aireuropa [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://tudominio.es/equipaje/problemas-de-equipaje/perdida-equipaje [P]
```